# Mac Catalyst version of working iOS App gets dyld crash

Tags: macos-catalina, mac-catalyst, pencilkit

I need to run a version of an existing iOS app in MacOS (10.15.7).
The app uses PencilKit and runs well in iOS 14. Compiling with Xcode 12.3
Trying to run in Catalina, the App crashes during dynamic framework loading before arriving at the app's AppDelegate.
the debugger says:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s9PencilKit8PKStrokeVMn
  Referenced from: /Users/.... (which was built for Mac OS X 14.0)
  Expected in: /System/iOSSupport/usr/lib/swift/libswiftPencilKit.dylib
 in /Users.... Sketch.app/Contents/MacOS/Hieroglyph Sketch
```

the contents of $arg1 = 6

Is this a clue that Catalyst now requires Big Sur?
Are there and funky Project or Target Settings required for MacOS builds not in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PencilKit is not supported in Catalina, despite what the docs say. It was enabled for Catalyst apps in Big Sur.

https://twitter.com/stroughtonsmith/status/1163514723679252480?s=21

Comment: Thanks!  What a pain!  I keep losing third party apps with every update :(